# declare global variable in kotlin defaulted to a property value

Tags: kotlin, micronaut

I am trying to load a global variable in kotlin directly from the application.yml:

```
telegram:
  token: foo
```

to achieve this, in my class I've tried this:

```
@Value("\${telegram.token}")
val botToken: String
```

But it is throwing an error saying that I need to initialize the property. (For example, this doesn't throw an error but it is not my expected behaviour):

```
@Value("\${telegram.token}")
val botToken: String = ""
```

What I want is to inject the config value (foo) into this constant (botToken).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either add it as a parameter in the constructor of the bean that contains the property:

```kotlin
class WhateverSpringManagedBeanClass(
    @Value("\${telegram.token}") private val botToken: String
)
```

Or try the following (this makes `botToken` mutable):

```kotlin
@Value("\${telegram.token}")
lateinit var botToken: String
```

Comment: this will work but it changes the val to a var so it will be mutable after this right? isn't there something similar to the lateinit var for vals?

Comment: If you turn `botToken` into a constructor parameter you can. I've updated my answer with an example.

Comment: ok, I accepted your answer but I would appreciate it if you add a comment explaining that the lateinit var would make it mutable since I was asking to keep it in a constant field.

Comment: Sure, will do ;)

Answer (score 1):

first of all it seems like you could use `@Property(name = "telegram.token")`

and then i would attempt

```
@Property(name = "telegram.token")
lateinit var token: String
    private set
```

Comment: as I mentioned it in Joao's answer, I wanted to avoid changing the field to a lateinit var since I don't want the token to be mutable.